# X labels in facet_wrap not rotating with ggplot and element_text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to graph some data from the following url: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/nypd-shooting-incident-data-historic

I want to create a small graph for each victim race in each borough. I have come to the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
data %>%
    drop_na(VIC_SEX) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = BORO))+
    geom_bar(aes(fill = BORO), show.legend = FALSE)+
    facet_wrap(~ VIC_RACE)
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)
          )+
    labs(title = "Dangerous Boroughs based on Race",
         x = "Borough",
         y = "Number of Shootings")
```

This has been producing the following:

[image: result]

As you can see that text is pretty much un-readable. I have also attempting removing the labels with

```
theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

but this does not remove them either. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code - you are missing a `+` after `facet_wrap()`. If you correct this, you can adjust the labels as required, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv("https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/833y-fsy8/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD")
#> Rows: 27312 Columns: 21
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr  (12): OCCUR_DATE, BORO, LOC_OF_OCCUR_DESC, LOC_CLASSFCTN_DESC, LOCATION...
#> dbl   (7): INCIDENT_KEY, PRECINCT, JURISDICTION_CODE, X_COORD_CD, Y_COORD_CD...
#> lgl   (1): STATISTICAL_MURDER_FLAG
#> time  (1): OCCUR_TIME
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

df %>%
  drop_na(VIC_SEX) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = BORO))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill = BORO), show.legend = FALSE)+
  facet_wrap(~ VIC_RACE) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))+
  labs(title = "Dangerous Boroughs based on Race",
       x = "Borough",
       y = "Number of Shootings")
```

[image]

```r
# adjust label placement
df %>%
  drop_na(VIC_SEX) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = BORO))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill = BORO), show.legend = FALSE)+
  facet_wrap(~ VIC_RACE) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
  labs(title = "Dangerous Boroughs based on Race",
       x = "Borough",
       y = "Number of Shootings")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: You're welcome; glad you solved your problem :)